# How to remove multiple tabs while reading file (cmd)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, readfile

Please help with this.

I have file like this:
http://www.crocko.com/9A60004ABE6046578ED113CFFFB75F6E/activate_all_regions.txt
*(Please click on the right bottom. There is timer but I did not find upload server without timer. In the file are tabulators, thats why I uploaded it on server)*

and this is script to read it:

```
    @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%1"=="" (
  IF EXIST "..\_install\activate all regions.txt" (
    SET FILE="..\_INSTALL\activate all regions.txt"
    echo Setting !FILE! as your configuration file
  ) ELSE (
   echo File not found. First argument is name of configuration file .txt.
   pause
  )
) else ( SET "FILE=%1")

for /F "skip=4 delims=pR tokens=1,2" %%a in ( 'reg query hkcu\environment /v temp' ) do set TAB=%%b

FOR /F "usebackq delims=!TAB! tokens=1-3" %%L IN (!FILE!) DO (
for /F "delims=!TAB! tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%%L") do echo A:"%%a"B:"%%b"C:"%%c"
REM echo %%L
)
```

I want to get output like:

```
A:"Directory name 1"B:"1"C:"Description to this line" 
A:"Directory name 2"B:"1"C:"Description to this line" 
A:"Directory name xxx"B:"1"C:"Description to this line"
```

The goal is to filter the tabs that are repeated (tab)(tab)(tab)(tab) and replace to one (tab).
So the first step needs to result in columnA(tab)columnB(tab)columnC(tab) and then in the second step to parse it to get the columns into three variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The !TAB! in the for command must be %TAB%:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "skip=4 delims=pR tokens=1,2" %%a in ( 'reg query hkcu\environment /v temp' ) do set TAB=%%b

SET FILE="activate all regions.txt"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=%TAB%" %%a IN (!FILE!) DO (
   echo A:"%%a" B:"%%b" C:"%%c"
)
```

Result:

```
A:"all_in_one" B:"1" C:""
A:"Ji×nÝ ╚echy st°ed" B:"1" C:""
A:"Ji×nÝ ╚echy v²chod - ╚B" B:"1" C:""
A:"Ji×nÝ ╚echy zßpad" B:"1" C:""
A:"Ji×nÝ Morava st°ed 1 - Znojmo" B:"1" C:""
A:"Ji×nÝ Morava st°ed 2 - Brno, B°eclav" B:"1" C:"Oblast od Brna a× po B°eclav."
A:"Ji×nÝ Morava v²chod 1 (Uh.Hrad.)" B:"1" C:""
A:"Ji×nÝ Morava v²chod 2 (Ji×nÝ Beskydy)" B:"1" C:""
A:"Ji×nÝ Morava zßpad - TelÞ" B:"1" C:""
A:"SevernÝ ╚echy" B:"1" C:""
A:"SevernÝ Morava v²chod - Ostravsko" B:"1" C:"Oblast zahrnuje Opavsko, Ostravsko, Okres Karvinß a Fr²dek MÝstek"
A:"SevernÝ Morava zßpad - Jesenicko" B:"1" C:"Oblast zahrnuje JesenÝk, Krnov, Bruntßl, R²ma°ov, Olomouc"
A:"St°ednÝ ╚echy 1 jih" B:"1" C:""
A:"St°ednÝ ╚echy 1 sever" B:"1" C:""
A:"St°ednÝ ╚echy 1 st°ed" B:"1" C:""
A:"St°ednÝ ╚echy 2 jih" B:"1" C:""
A:"St°ednÝ ╚echy 2 sever" B:"1" C:""
A:"St°ednÝ ╚echy 2 st°ed" B:"1" C:""
A:"V²chodnÝ ╚echy jih" B:"1" C:""
A:"ZßpadnÝ ╚echy jih" B:"1" C:""
A:"ZßpadnÝ ╚echy sever" B:"1" C:""
A:"ZßpadnÝ ╚echy st°ed (K.Vary)" B:"1" C:""
A:"ZßpadnÝ Morava" B:"1" C:"Oblast zahrnuje Prostýjov, Zßb°eh, èumperk"
```

Comment: Wow. That was simple. But why is there %TAB% and not !TAB! when there is Delayed Expansion enabled?

Comment: NOte to your #4 line code: Hello again. Is this command working on Windows 7? aGerman: "As far as I know XP is the last Windows version wherer REG QUERY returns the values tab-separated. That means your solution doesn't work for Vista and Win7."